# Split String having commas or 'and ' in one string

Tags: split, google-bigquery

```
SELECT 
SPLIT('Ben Hobson, Jane McGuire and Kerry McCarthy',',');
```

returns

| SPLIT('Ben Hobson, Jane McGuire and Kerry McCarthy',',') |
| --- |
| Ben Hobson |
| Jane McGuire and Kerry McCarthy |

expected output :

| SPLIT('Ben Hobson, Jane McGuire and Kerry McCarthy',',') |
| --- |
| Ben Hobson |
| Jane McGuire |
| Kerry McCarthy |

How do I achieve this in BigQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below

```sql
SELECT SPLIT(REPLACE('Ben Hobson, Jane McGuire and Kerry McCarthy','and', ','))
```

Note that you need to **TRIM** each name to remove spaces around it with above query.

or, if a comma followed by  a space is guaranteed, you can try this instead.

```sql
SELECT SPLIT(REPLACE('Ben Hobson, Jane McGuire and Kerry McCarthy',' and', ','), ', ')
```

[image]